# get output dapper with query executed

Tags: parameters, output, dapper

I have code that executes a query in sqlserver accessing with dapper in the error exception I want to get the query executed with the specified parameter:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine(" SELECT " + campoChave + " AS CODIGO, ");
sql.AppendLine("        " + campoSelecao + " AS DESCRICAO ");
sql.AppendLine("   FROM " + tabela);
sql.AppendLine("   where codigoidioma = @codigoIdioma");
sql.AppendLine("  ORDER BY " + campoSelecao);

IEnumerable entities2 = conexao.Query<ComboBoxGenerico>(sql.ToString(), new { codigoIdioma = 1 });
```

this code is with error I want to get the query after executing the dapper with the command

Ex: select teste as codigo ..... where codigoidioma = 1

@codigoIdioma ---> 1

Comment: small note: if you're going to use `StringBuilder`, it would be better to use it *throughout*, i.e. `sql.Append(" SELECT ").Append(campoChave).AppendLine(" AS CODIGO, ");`, etc; it also goes without saying that you need to be *really* careful not to allow user input into `campoChave`, `campoSelecao`, etc - as that would allow SQL injection

Comment: If you want to log the queries, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875558/5779732) may help even though it uses Dapper Extensions. Internally, it creates [profiled connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194760/how-to-get-last-executed-sql-query-by-sqlconnection#comment88851870_50925790) which is then used for logging.

Answer (score 0):

The query after executing the command will almost always be... exactly what you passed in. Dapper doesn't *replace* parameter tokens - that would be a SQL-injection hole. Even with tools that monitor SQL traffic (mini-profiler, SQL server profiler, etc): the command shown will include parameter tokens, with the parameters sent separately.

Mini-profiler *spoofs this*, by (in the display) prepending the command with `declare` statements that look like the parameters, so you can run it in SSMS - that will give you something like:

```sql
declare @codigoidioma int = 1;
select teste as codigo ..... where codigoidioma = @codigoidioma
```

but note that it remained parameterized (ish) even here.

In the case of dapper *specifically*, there *are* some exceptions to the "it'll be what you passed in" general rule, concerning some specific scenarios such as `in @foo` (for something like a `List<int>` for `foo`), where it will generate an appropriate parameter expansion, but *it will still be parameterized*.

Comment: in this example above to get easy the generated query, but in case it is an insert or update code that in the case would be passed as a parameter a language object with all the properties how would I get this query?

Comment: @user3576807 which exact methods are you using? are you using dapper.contrib etc, for example? in those cases, I would again say "miniprofiler" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/) - not directly tied to dapper, but it is by the same team, and it is what we use in conjunction with dapper for our own system/query monitoring (we use it on every single page request here on Stack Overflow, for example); but again: it will *only* give you the parameterized form, not the form with parameters replaced, because **dapper doesn't do that**