# Can parameter values be suppressed in Exceptions thrown by NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892191/639520), NHibernate includes the SQL of queries as well as parameter values when it encounters an ADO exception. Due to data sensitivity concerns, I need to redact or suppress the values of parameters that were sent to the database so that they don't end up in application logs.
Is there a way to configure NHibernate so that it does not include the parameter values? Or something that I can override to achieve that?

Comment: If you have a global exception handler, catch/filter it there and rethrow your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your own custom dialect overriding the [`BuildSQLExceptionConverter`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/7f60bc3a875a721d6ad4b76b530f2447da79454f/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Dialect.cs#L2666-L2672) method for yielding a custom `NHibernate.Exceptions.ISQLExceptionConverter`. (See [its default implementation](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Exceptions/SQLStateConverter.cs), or see [examples in the test project](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate.Test/ExceptionsTest).)

Removing the parameter values here will likely imply some dirty hacking of the `Message` and/or `Sql` properties values of the `exceptionInfo` parameter received by the `Convert` method.

There is currently no way to prevent NHibernate from formatting the sql parameters values in these properties values.

Using a custom dialect is usually done by extending the one your application is currently using, then configuring it with the [`dialect`](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) setting.